# Show strings with only words (no numbers) in command line (terminal)

Tags: regex, grep

How can you extract strings with only words connected with an underscore but without numbers in the Command Prompt. ("grep -o" is preferred to use)

```
"id";"string";"string":
"11";"tomato_banana_apple";"8"
"14";"error_book_10_table_206";"1_apple_peach"
```

So, I want the string from the second column to be without any digits. The first and the last column can, however, contain digits.

The output should be:

```
"11";"tomato_banana_apple";"8"
```

So far, I've tried: `grep -o "[a-z]+_[a-z]+" filename.csv`

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output you want from the the sample data. Also, show what you have tried.

Comment: You've got numbers on each line. If you did what you are asking then it would return no lines. You need to extract the string 2 from the semicolon separated list and then perform the pattern match on that. Might be a fairly long command.

Comment: `-o` option output only-match, you can't have the whole line. Do you want to output the whole line (i.e. `"11";"tomato_banana_apple";"8"`) or only match (I;e. `tomato_banana_apple`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending whether you want only the matched string or not, you can do:

```
grep -o "\b[[:alpha:]]\+\(_[[:alpha:]]\+\)\+\b" filename.csv
tomato_banana_apple
```

OR

```
grep  "\b[[:alpha:]]\+\(_[[:alpha:]]\+\)\+\b" filename.csv
"11";"tomato_banana_apple";"8"
```

Or use the `-P` option for PCRE:

```
grep -P "\b[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)+\b"
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b                      # word boundary
[[:alpha:]]\+           # 1 or more alpha
\(                      # star group
    _                   # 1 underscore
    [[:alpha:]]\+       # 1 or more alpha
\)\+                    # end group, may appear 1 or more times
\b                      # word boundary
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the right outcome thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

With *basic* regular expressions, you need `\+` to match one or more. It is *extended* regular expressions (`grep -E`) that uses `+` without a backslash

```
grep '"[[:alpha:]_]\+"' filename.csv
```

Are you sure you want the `-o` option? Given your desired output, I'd suggest you don't.

Comment: This command still gives me strings with digits. I want to have only letters/ words.

Comment: In your question, "the output should be ..." contains digits. Is that wrong? What output do you *really* want?

Comment: Mm, okay, I didn't explain it correctly. The strings made of words that are connected by the underscore, may not contain digits. I can still have "id" (digits) and single digits as "8" (in the first row of the example).

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1445715/edit) to clarify.